# TCP sequence number question

Tags: tcp

This is more of a theoretical question than an actual problem I have.

If I understand correctly, the sequence number in the TCP header of a packet is the index of the first byte in the packet in the whole stream, correct? If that is the case, since the sequence number is an unsigned 32-bit integer, then what happens after more than FFFFFFFF = 4294967295 bytes are transferred? Will the sequence number wrap around, or will the sender send a SYN packet to restart at 0?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The sequence number loops back to 0. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol):

[image]

> TCP sequence numbers and receive
> windows behave very much like a clock.
> The receive window shifts each time
> the receiver receives and acknowledges
> a new segment of data. Once it runs
> out of sequence numbers, the sequence
> number loops back to 0.

Also see chapter 4 of [RFC 1323](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1323).

Answer (score 25):

It wraps. RFC 793:

> It is essential to remember that the actual sequence number space is finite, though very large. This space ranges from 0 to 2**32 - 1. Since the space is finite, all arithmetic dealing with sequence numbers must be performed modulo 2**32. This unsigned arithmetic preserves the relationship of sequence numbers as they cycle from 2**32 - 1 to 0 again. There are some subtleties to computer modulo arithmetic, so great care should be taken in programming the comparison of such values. The symbol "=<" means "less than or equal" (modulo 2**32).

Read more: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc793.html#ixzz0lcD37K7J

Answer (score 15):

The sequence number is not actually the "index of the first byte in the packet in the whole stream" since sequence numbers deliberately start at a random value (this is to stop a form of attack known as the [TCP Sequence Prediction Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Sequence_Prediction_Attack)).

No SYN is required, the sequence number simply loops back to zero again once it gets to the limit.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Didn't know sequence numbers started at a random value. I understand what Wireshark means when it says "relative number" now.

Comment: It's not clear that an initial sequence number would meaningfully mitigate such an attack. The designers of TCP/IP specified the "Initial Sequence Number" as a value seeded by a clock to prevent possible confusion in the event that a new connection was created with the same source/destination as a prior connection that still had packets in-flight in the network. See "Initial Sequence Number Selection" in http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt