# TCP timeout is not clear

Tags: tcp, timeout

i read

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2018

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5681

but i still not understand the protocol the timeout occurrence.

let's say for examples that i want send 3 segments:

i send 1 , and get ack, so not the cwind increase to 2

now i send 2+3 and get ack only on 3(the segment number 2 lost)
so i will enter to timeout,
and what will be after the timeout?
i will send segment number 2+3 / or only segment number 2 (like selective repete)

i need that information because i marked on quize that segment number 2+3 will send again. but i not see that spesipic on protocol.
so i must find information that support on my answer.

pleae help me

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> now i send 2+3 and get ack only on 3(the segment number 2 lost) so i will enter to timeout, and what will be after the timeout? i will send segment number 2+3 / or only segment number 2 (like selective repete)

You don't get ACK for segments, but for sequence numbers. If you got the ACK containing the end sequence for segment 3 it means that all data until the end of segment 3 were received, which includes the data from segment 2. So no retransmission is needed.

If selective ACK's (SACK) are used you get the start and the end sequence number. This way the peer could report back that it received segment 3 but not segment 2, in which case you only need to retransmit segment 2.

Comment: hi and thanks for your reply
yeh what i mean is get ack for sequence numbers.

so what you say is,:
1) if the option SACK if turn on,   so the user can know start and the end sequence number and send specipic segment that miss?(only 2 on my example)
2)if the SACK is turn off he need to send 2+3(on my examples?)

if is correct i need 2 answer please
a) i understand that Sequence Number is 32 bit, so how it can be tell me  the start and the end on segment he get?

b) where on the tcp header i see if SACK it turn of or turn on?
thanks!

Comment: @dani1999: please try to write english and not slang. I have really problems to understand what you mean. As for SACK - see http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/17/tcp-selective-acknowledgments-sack/. And for 32 bit, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672734/tcp-sequence-number-question.

Comment: hi , i sorry about me low english.. i realy try
so what i get until now is....
according to RFC1072 and RFC 2,018
there is option to add SACK  telling me witch the start and the end of bytes that i get... 
so if i use on SACK (on my example i will send only the 2 segment again
i add the SACK on the TCP OPTION HEADER 

but the default is (if i not use on option) that i will send 2+3 again?
thanks!!!

Comment: Again: if you got the ACK for the end of segment 3 than all is received and nothing needs to be resent. If you got an SACK for only segment 3 then you must resent only segment 2, because the recipient told you that 3 was received.

Comment: yeh i got it
but what is the basic? if i not use on SACK option?
the basic is like GBN? the user will need to send 2+3?(if segment 2 is lost?)
thanks!

Comment: @dani1999  If segment 2 is lost then you don't get an ACK for the end of segment 3. Thus the sender has no knowledge if segment 3 might be received and thus should resent segment 2 and 3.

Comment: let's say that i have 3 segment to send,

send segment 1 and get ack, cwind is 2.

Then I send 2+3 , but segment 2 is gone.

So i come to TIMEOUT (so cwind down to 1)

no what will happend?

I ask before and see rfc 2018 and according to this article http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/17/tcp-selective-acknowledgments-sack/

i understand that if i not use on SACK . so i will need send again 2+3 segment

but... someone told me that this artile is not correct because on rfc 793 (and not change from then) i will need send again only the 2 segment who is right?

Comment: @dani1999: if one side has sent multiple segments and it gets the ACK only for some of them it must retransmit the rest. And if SACK is not used this means all segments starting from the last one which was ACKed - in your case segments 2 and 3. Because it has no way to know if segment 3 might have been received.

Comment: I so thank you... but my teaher tell me that is not correct because on RFC 793 write
"
  RETRANSMISSION TIMEOUT
 For any state if the retransmission timeout expires on a segment in
 the retransmission queue, send the segment at the front of the
 retransmission queue again, reinitialize the retransmission timer,
 and return.
"

so he say that he need send only segment number 2
because when i send again segment 2 the reciver will send me ack on 2+3
and that not change from then.
i will be so happy if you tell me if he wronge according of RFC 793 becauase he totally base on it
thank you so much!

Comment: he tell that base on RFC 793 the reciver save the segment 3 and not drop it (like selective repete)
and when he get the segment 2 he back ack on 2+3
i must prove he wrong. that my final test
but i can only prove it according to RFC (like he say that RFC 793 tell i wrong)
 because i tried to prive according to
http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/17/tcp-selective-acknowledgments-sack/
that i i not use sack the reciver not save the segment 3 but he tell that packetlife wrong according to RFC 793
thanks!!!

Comment: @dani1999: If only the retransmission timeout for segment 2 is expired then only this segment needs to be resent. If the retransmission timeout for both expired then both will be resent. Your question implies that 2+3 are both transmitted at the same time, so they will both have the same retransmission timeout.

Comment: on the qustion tell that we send 3 segment 1 after 1
but. does it metter?
according to arctile that i linked (not talk about timeout but anyway)
if i not use SACK i need send 2+3 becauase the recevier not save the segment
so you tell the article is wrong?

Comment: @dani1999: last try to explain it to you: if 2+3 are sent at the same time the transmission timeout is the same and both will be retransmitted. If instead 2+3 are not sent at the same time the retranmission timeout for 2 will expire before the one for segment 3 and only 2 will be retranmitted. If this results in ACK for 2+3 before the retransmission timeout for 3 triggers than 3 will not sent. If it gets only an ACK for 2 segment 3 must be sent again.